# How to create circular selection checkboxes in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uicollectionview, ios11

Here's a screenshot from the *Files* browser in iOS 11. When you tap the *Select* button you see these circular checkboxes. Many apps have something similar.

Are these checkboxes in the `UIKit` library for other developers can use (maybe a subclass of `UISwitch` or some mode of a `UICollectionView`), or do we need to write a custom class to make something look like that?

[image]

Comment: There are not a standard part of UIKit.  You will need to create your own or look for open source or similar

Comment: I'd start with a compound view, then consider simply using a image of some sort to display the selected and unselected states

Comment: You can use a background image of a button or use something like [BEMCheckBox](https://github.com/Boris-Em/BEMCheckBox)

Comment: Try this https://github.com/vladislav-k/VKCheckbox?files=1

Comment: Thanks all. I drew a similar checkbox in a graphics program and used a `UIImageView`. It works fine.